No access to Ubuntu desktop
When I start Ubuntu I get the following error messages, and then it stays there forever and does not start Ubuntu. What can I do to solve this and have access again to the desktop?
ACPI errors:


Follow up information:
Hello, first of all thank you for your efforts to help me. I will try to explain and provide more information so that you can understand better. I am using Ubuntu for many years. I was using for the last 3 years Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Last week it gave me a notification that I can upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 I think and I clicked yes. So it did it's update and since then I had issues. In the beginning I could login over the group menu and choose from the advanced options. Since few days even this is not any longer possible. It just stays at the screen with the error message on the pictures I attached. @David you are correct. I have switch off the laptop several times because it was constantly freezing. I am doing this for years now. I did not know what else to do. So I was switching the laptop off and on again. I had few issues with the journal in the past but found ways to solve it. The error message shown on the pictures looks like:
• 9] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.NLBU._STA due to previous error
MOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
0.'540322] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.NLBU—STA.N
]. AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[ 0.540349] ACPI Erro4: Aborting method _SB.NLBU._STA due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730408rSe-529)
[ 0.617774] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.NLBU._STA.N
LVD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[ 0.617817] ACPI Errbr: Aborting method _SB.NLBU._STA due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 463346/15597568 files, 61767025/62383360 blocks
5.329486] ACPI•Error: No handler for Region [RCNO] (0000000080f7366f) [SystemCMOS] (20210730/e0egion-130)
5.329553] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=S) has no handler (20210730/exf1dio-261)
5.329608] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.NMID.ESDT due to previous error (AE_NOT_ExIST) (20210730/psparse-529)
5.329665] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.PCIO.LPCO.ECO—Q42 due to previous error (AE_NOT_ExIST) (20210730/psparse-529)

Use "edit"  and add information about your system to the question. Also tell a little about the context. Is this the first time you try installing Ubuntu, or did it previously work, and the problem then suddenly appear?

I see a recovering journal there was the system shut down with the power switch and if so how many times and why.

I have edited my question and inserted more information. Thank you.
